# How to create Django sophisticated pdf template?

Tags: django, pdf

I need to create in Django sophisticated pdf documents that will be populated with some variable fields.

I am already generating simple pdfs

> reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

but customer requires pdfs where pdf is assembled from several text blocks and not simple row based.

[image]

Is there easy way to do it?

Comment: ReportLab [user guide](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf) has many examples on multi column layouts. Did you try anything? What did not work?

Comment: There are quite a few options. You can design html templates in a way you want your report to be and then convert those html templates to pdf. In this way you have control over design. You can wkhtmltopdf. Explore it, its nice.